# CSS animation does not work properly in iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, css-animations

My task is to create a pulsing animation on the background that is under the .img.

[My code structure looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNr8i.jpg)

My CSS:

```
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.glow-bg {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/11/18/26/bokeh-4542479_1280.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;  
  position: absolute;

  opacity: .99;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.main-img {
  z-index: 100;  
  margin-top: 185px;   
  width: 300px;
}

.animation {
  -webkit-animation: load 2s infinite 0s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation: load 2s infinite 0s ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load {
0% {
    -webkit-opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  }
}

@keyframes load {
0%{
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: blur(5px);
    }
100%{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    }
  }
```

Of course, I posted here only a piece of code, not all of it.

[The final option is supposed to look like on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD7zF.jpg)

But that's not all, because I work on a backend where the requirement is inline CSS, so all this code is converted to inline CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
    <meta charset="utf-8" style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
    <style> @-webkit-keyframes load { 0% {-webkit-opacity: 0.2; -webkit-filter: blur(5px);}} @keyframes load { 0% { opacity: 0.2; filter: blur(5px); }} </style>
  </head>
  
  <body style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;color: #fff;font-size: 1em;font-weight: 400;line-height: 1.5;background: #fff;text-align: center;display: flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;">
    <div class="container" style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;flex-grow: 1;position: relative;width: auto;max-width: 600px;background: #fff;color: #fff;text-align: center;display: flex;flex-direction: column;font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 1em;">          
      <div class="wrapper" style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;display: flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;position: relative;">
        <div class="glow-bg animation" style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/11/18/26/bokeh-4542479_1280.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: center;position: absolute;opacity: .99;height: 500px;width: 600px;top: 40px;z-index: 0;-webkit-animation: load 2s infinite 0s ease-in-out;-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;animation: load 2s infinite 0s ease-in-out;animation-direction: alternate;"></div>
        <img class="main-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/26/12/32/feather-4431599_960_720.jpg" alt="img" style="box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;padding: 0;height: auto;max-width: 100%;z-index: 100;margin-top: 185px;width: 300px;">
      </div>      
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

So the final version of this piece of code looks like the above and everything works on all devices and search engines, except iOS. On the iPhone, the glow from the background goes into the front, hiding the image. I have the impression that maybe my -webkit- implementation is not ok.
Sorry, I used random photos from the internet just wanted to give you an idea.
I hope this piece is enough for you to help and advise me.

Comment: It works OK on my iPad (IOS 15 Safari). What device and version numbers are you using?

Comment: It's iPhone 11, and Chrome browser.
Thanks for checking :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.